# Multiple values into one cell SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have an item A than has one-many relationship with Table T1 (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4).

Currently I am retrieving data from T1 for Item A in XML into a single column. Is there any more efficient way to do so rather than parsing into XML.

The thing is in my query I have 1 column for Table T1's value.

Comment: As per **first normal form** of database design - each cell should contain **no more than ONE value** ....

Comment: My database design is normalized. It's just that i want to get it done in my query in a single column.

Comment: You're going to need to post some sample data or table structures, queries you've tried, and desired outputs.  Your question is too abstract and therefore too ambiguous or too broad.

Comment: So you are trying to create a comma delimited list? Here is one way to do this. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/comma+separated+list/71700/